# Use typedef in union

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I want to redeifine the float using:

```
typedef float decimal
```

because i'm using "uthash" table and it doesn't hava a method add_float
it can only me done through a struct

i used this in bison

```
%union{
   decimal dec;
}
and then declare the token
%token <dec> DECIMAL
```

if I do in the flex

```
{DECIMAL} {yylval.dec=atof(yytext); return (DECIMAL);}
```

it tells me:
ERRORS in the flex document:
YYSTYPE has no member named dec

ERRORS in the bison (in the union)
expected specifier-qualifier-list before decimal.

Any ideas?
Any help appreciated!

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Adobe Flex?

Comment: My guess is he is referring to flex, the fast lexical analyzer tool. The tag for that is gnu-flex.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a few issues.

First, your flex rule `{DECIMAL} {yylval.dec=atof(yytext); return (DECIMAL);}` makes no sense. Is `DECIMAL` a macro or replacement for some matching regexp pattern? It does not appear so because `DECIMAL` is declared as a TOKEN in Bison.

Anyway, the simple issue in your union for yylval in Bison is the type `decimal` was not declared anywhere. You should have `typedef decimal float` declared somewhere in your bison file and your flex file. This is what the error message

```
ERRORS in the bison (in the union) expected specifier-qualifier-list before decimal.
```

is referring to more than 99% of the time.

Now, to solve that issue you would need to either put it in a separate file and include that file into both the flex and bison files. This is messy, and a simpler approach is to just put it in the first section of the bison file (first part where C code goes). Then, if you use

```
bison -d myfile.y
```

you would get a new file called `myfile.tab.h` (along with the myfile.tab.c). The header should be included in the flex file. If you look in that header file, you will see all of your %token definitions also appear in it, so you can make a change at any time in bison and not need to worry about making the same changes in the flex file.

Comment: DECIMAL with capital letters is the name of a TOKEN

Comment: Ok, but your yylval has a type <code>decimal</code> Where is this declared? Also, you have {DECIMAL} in flex, which means when flex encounters DECIMAL (which is a token), it will do the actions. Since DECIMAL is a token, it has some value (258 or higher). Do you see how this makes no sense?

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, my second paragraph in my answer is referring to the DECIMAL used in {DECIMAL}.